# BlackBerry plugin for Eclipse. Mac OS

Tags: eclipse, macos, blackberry

I`m trying to run my application.
And below error appear:

**Lunching BlakberryHelloWorldApp has encountered a problem There is no connected blackberry device**

I was thinking that Blackberry eclipse plugin contains a blackberry device. 
How can I add this devise to eclipse?

Comment: You need into install the [Simulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_installing.html) provided by blackberry

Comment: I`ve installed this simulator already,
but I can`t connect eclipse to it(

Comment: If this is for BlackBerry 10, you should use the `blackberry-10` tag on your question.

Comment: Yes, I should. Does anybody know what me to do with that problem?